# Display list of colors and their names in a combobox

Tags: vb.net, graphics, combobox, rectangles, drawrectangle

I'm trying to display a list of colors in a combobox. Each item in the box contains the name of a color suffixed by a rectangle filled with the corresponding color as shown in a project [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34332/Color-Picker-Combo-Box-2).

The project is written in c#. I don't understand c#  so I've converted the codes to vb .net as shown below.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ColorList As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim colorType As Type = GetType(System.Drawing.Color)
    Dim propInfoList As PropertyInfo() = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.[Static] Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or BindingFlags.[Public])

    For Each c As PropertyInfo In propInfoList
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(c.Name)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Combobox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DrawItem
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim rect As Rectangle = e.Bounds

    If e.Index >= 0 Then
        Dim n As String = (CType(sender, ComboBox)).Items(e.Index).ToString()
        Dim f As Font = New Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular)
        Dim c As Color = Color.FromName(n)
        Dim b As Brush = New SolidBrush(c)
        g.DrawString(n, f, Brushes.Black, rect.X, rect.Top)
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, rect.X + 110, rect.Y + 5, rect.Width - 10, rect.Height - 10)
    End If
End Sub
```

When I execute the above code, the combo box `Combobox1` displays items with only the names of the color. The colored rectangles are not displayed as show in the project I've linked above.
What's causing the rectangles not be displayed?
I've tried setting `Combobox1`'s  `DrawMode` to all available DrawModes. Nothing worked.

Note, I've used [Telerik's code converter](https://converter.telerik.com/) to convert the c# code to vb .net code.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the _Background_ part of that article? IE. Setting the DrawMode to DrawModeFixed?

Comment: @Steve after setting the draw mode to OwnerDrawFixed it's working. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve But the rectangles again disappear when the combobox's DropDownStyle is set to 'Simple'

Comment: Please don't use ArrayList in new code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

Comment: @Mary No I'm not using the ArrayList. I've removed the button click event from my code. Thanks for the advice anyway. It was helpful.

Comment: @Steve Ok the problem was with the rectangles' size being dependent on size of the combobox. I solved it by setting the width and height of the rectangles to a constant number. Now the DropDownStyle of the combobox is not creating any problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim N As String = (CType(sender, ComboBox)).Items(e.Index).ToString()
Dim F As Font = New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
Dim B As Brush = New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
Dim C As Color = Color.FromName(N)
Dim P As Brush = New SolidBrush(C)
Dim L As Pen = New Pen(e.ForeColor)
Dim R1 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 2, e.Bounds.Top + 2, 50, e.Bounds.Height - 4)
Dim R2 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 3, e.Bounds.Top + 3, 48, e.Bounds.Height - 6)
Dim R3 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 2, e.Bounds.Top + 2, 50, e.Bounds.Height - 4)
Dim R4 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 2, e.Bounds.Top + 2, 50, e.Bounds.Height - 4)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(L, R1)
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(P, R2)
e.Graphics.DrawString(N, F, B, e.Bounds.Left + 65, e.Bounds.Top + 2)

e.DrawFocusRectangle()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.